# Vue code working in Typescript 2.8.3 but breaks in 2.9.2 - Property does not exist "xxx" foo in Vue (or somewhere similar)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

We have a working / compiling (fairly large) Vue application that compiles and runs just fine when using Typescript 2.8.3 -- but gives dozens of errors in some components when upgrading to 2.9.2.

The Vue component definition looks like (abbreviated):

```
export default Vue.extend({
extends: BaseFormControl,

name: 'VDateSelect',

inheritAttrs: false,

props: {
  /**
  * A unique id used to create ids for the contained select menus.
  */
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  /**
  * @model
  */
  value: {
    type: [Date as Prop<Date>, String as Prop<string>],
    required: true,
  },
  /**
  * Determines if the field is required; applies the `required` attribute to the contained select menus.
  */
  required: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  /**
  * The label text used for the contained `legend`.
  */
  label: {
    type: String,
  },
  /**
  * Visually hides the label without hiding it from screen readers.
  */
  hideLabel: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  /**
  * A uniqe `name` attribute value used to generate `name` attribute values for the contained select menus.
  */
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  /**
  * An `Array` containing two dates. The first is the start date; the second is the end date. This range is used to generate year options.
  * The default range is the current date plus four years out.
  */
  range: {
    type: Array,
    default() {
      const today = startOfDay(new Date());

      return [today, addYears(today, 4)];
    },
  } as PropOptions<Array<Date>>,
  /**
  * Applied to the contained selects; should be used to connect fields to their error messages (for accessibility).
  */
  ariaDescribedby: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
},

data() {
  return {
    monthValue: isDate(this.value) ? `${startOfDay(this.value).getMonth()}` : '',
    dayValue: isDate(this.value) ? `${startOfDay(this.value).getDate()}` : '',
    yearValue: isDate(this.value) ? `${startOfDay(this.value).getFullYear()}` : '',
    monthOptions,
    dayOptions,
  };
},

computed: {
  month: {
    get: function(): string {
      return this.monthValue;
    },
    set: function(value: string) {
      this.monthValue = value;

      this.updateValue(value === '');
    },
  },

  day: {
    get: function(): string {
      return this.dayValue;
    },
    set: function(value: string) {
      this.dayValue = value;

      this.updateValue(value === '');
    },
  },

  year: {
    get: function(): string {
      return this.yearValue;
    },
    set: function(value: string) {
      this.yearValue = value;

      this.updateValue(value === '');
    },
  },

  yearOptions: function() {
    const [startDate, endDate] = this.range;
    const options = [{ label: 'Year', value: '' }];
    const diff = differenceInCalendarYears(endDate, startDate);

    for (let i = 0; i <= diff; i++) {
      const value = `${addYears(startDate, i).getFullYear()}`;
      options.push({ label: value, value });
    }

    return options;
  },
},
```

...

The error messages all have to do with some property not being defined..these are in the props: area and being used down in data() and computed: and some other similar things.  Some sample errors are below:

ERROR in /Users/sjm/work/mm/mms4/web-ui/src/app/shared/components/VDateSelect/VDateSelect.vue.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/sjm/work/mm/mms4/web-ui/src/app/shared/components/VDateSelect/VDateSelect.vue.ts(140,59)
      TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Vue'.

ERROR in /Users/sjm/work/mm/mms4/web-ui/src/app/shared/components/VDateSelect/VDateSelect.vue.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/sjm/work/mm/mms4/web-ui/src/app/shared/components/VDateSelect/VDateSelect.vue.ts(141,29)
      TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Vue'.

And a bit different:

ERROR in /Users/sjm/work/mm/mms4/web-ui/src/app/shared/components/VDateSelect/VDateSelect.vue.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/sjm/work/mm/mms4/web-ui/src/app/shared/components/VDateSelect/VDateSelect.vue.ts(151,21)
      TS2339: Property 'monthValue' does not exist on type 'ComputedOptions | (() => any)'.
  Property 'monthValue' does not exist on type 'ComputedOptions'.

Etc.  The tslinter within VSCode isn't complaining about any of it .. just when I run it in the build cycle etc.

I have no idea what changed between TS 2.8.3 and 2.9.2 to break this but .. ugh!  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: sjmcdowall have you been able to figure out what the issue is? Currently facing very similar issue you are facing

Comment: Honestly I haven't gone back and looked at this in a long time -- although TS is now upgraded again to 3 I think?  I am now doing a Flutter/Dart app and won't get back to this ...sorry

Comment: Getting the same issue just today :(

Comment: @WildanMaulanaSyahidillah I manage to solve all my issues I had with TS... All the issues was related to correctly annotating vue props... if you post example of the props that is causing issues for you I might be able to help you out. (no promises thou ;))

Comment: A bit different but similar error `Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue, {}, {}, {}, Readonly<{}>>'.`  on `errorMap: { type: Object, default: () => ({})}, loading: { type: boolean, default: false }` on prop definition. After removing the default value for `errorMap`, the error is gone. seems like ts issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8679